# C# - txtbox.Undo() not working as expected for Del key

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a Notepad variant in Visual Studio (Winform, C#). It has a toolstrip, with options such as Undo, Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, etc. The shortcut keys are enabled and connected with the menu options (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, etc).

The rest of the Notepad variant is filled with a multiline textbox.

The problem arises when I want to delete the text from the textbox via the Delete key, or the menu option - while that works (i.e. the characters to the right of the current caret position are deleted, selected characters are deleted, etc), I am unable to undo that specific action.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
private void mnuCut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtbox.SelectedText != "")
    {
        txtbox.Cut();
    }
}

private void mnuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtbox.SelectedText != "")
    {
        txtbox.Copy();
    }
}

private void mnuPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) == true)
    {
        if(txtbox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            txtbox.SelectionStart = txtbox.SelectionStart + txtbox.SelectionLength;
        }

        txtbox.Paste();
    }
}

private void mnuUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtbox.CanUndo == true)
    {
        txtbox.Undo();
        txtbox.ClearUndo();
    }
}

private void txtbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Delete
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if(txtbox.SelectionLength < 1)
        {
            txtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
        }
        txtbox.SelectedText = "";
    }

    // Select all
    if(e.Modifiers == Keys.ControlKey && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        txtbox.SelectAll();
    }
}

private void mnuDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtbox.SelectionLength < 1)
    {
        txtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
    }
    txtbox.SelectedText = "";
}

private void selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtbox.SelectAll();
}
```

I think the problem may be in the way I'm deleting characters with the `mnuDelete_Click` and `KeyUp` event handlers. The same thing happens if I replace `txtbox.SelectedText = ""` with `txtbox.SelectedText = String.Empty`.

I know that I might be better off by using, say, `txtbox.Cut()`, like this:

```
private void txtbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Delete
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if(txtbox.SelectionLength < 1)
        {
            txtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
        }
        //txtbox.SelectedText = "";
        txtbox.Cut();
    }

    // Select all
    if(e.Modifiers == Keys.ControlKey && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        txtbox.SelectAll();
    }
}

private void mnuDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtbox.SelectionLength < 1)
    {
        txtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
    }
    //txtbox.SelectedText = "";
    txtbox.Cut();
}
```

But, even though this works, it'll replace the current contents of the clipboard with whatever was deleted / cut, which is something I don't want.

Finally, I ended up using `SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}")`, and that gave the desired functionality. But the solution *doesn't feel right* - the original action was pressing the Delete key, not the Backspace key.

So, my question is this - how can delete characters via the Delete key, and obtain the ability to undo it, without resorting to hacky solutions? Or does it make no difference in the end, because it works as it is?

Comment: It's not clear why you're trying to handle e.g., `Keys.Delete` and `CTRL+A`, when these base functions are already handled by the Control itself. `Undo` functionality included. -- If you need to handle some custom (not System) Keys combination, use the `KeyDown` event, not `KeyUp`. Or override `ProcessCmdKey` in a Custom Control (or WndProc).

Comment: And how exact does your `undo` works ?

Comment: @Jimi Point taken for `CTRL + A`, but pressing Delete while in textbox does nothing, that's why I'm handling it.

Comment: @GuidoG I can undo things deleted via Backspace, or things I've typed in, or things copied, pasted, but whatever is deleted via Delete (and the logic `textbox.SelectedText = ""` can not be undone. If there isn't a handler for pressing Delete, the key itself does nothing.

Comment: Pressing Delete or BackSpace to delete text can be undone pressing `CTRL+Z` as usual or calling `[TextBox].Undo()`. If it doesn't work with your app, then you're causing it to fail, possibly clearing the internal Undo queue or overwriting the restored text section that was just undeleted (since it's automatically selected).